# Android Image blured round corners

Tags: android, image

I have list of images. I have rounded the corners of my image by using this function:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = null;
        try {
            if(bitmap != null) {
                output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

                final int color = 0xff424242;
                final Paint paint = new Paint();
                final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
                final float roundPx = pixels;

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
//              canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                paint.setColor(color);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

It successfully rounds the corners of image, but the corners are blurred, rough and pixelated. Corners are not smooth. Sample output is:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your code, but I use this code:

```
public static Bitmap roundBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
    Paint paintForRound = new Paint();
    paintForRound.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintForRound.setColor(0xff424242);
    paintForRound.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paintForRound.setXfermode(null);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paintForRound);

    paintForRound.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paintForRound);

    return output;
}
```

This code gives pixel-perfect result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the corner radius using this formula

```
float roundPx = bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight() ? ((float) bitmap.getHeight())/6 : ((float) bitmap.getWidth())/6;
        roundPx = roundPx < 10 ? 10 : roundPx;
```